# Get length of longest line segment in svg unsig javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, measure

I want to find a way to get the length of the longest line segment in a svg path. Since a path can jump from one point to another the `getTotalLength()` command doesn't work. As a simple example look at the following path:

```
<path d="
    M 0 0  L 100 0
    M 0 10 L 50 10
    M 0 20 L 150 20
">
```

While `getTotalLength()` outputs `300`, I want `150` as my output.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem. It works by splitting the path in multiple segments and measuring the seperately:

```
function maxSectionLength(path){
    let segments = path.attributes.d.value.split(/(?=[m,M])/),
        testPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"path"),
        max = 0;
    for(let d of segments){
        testPath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d)
        max = Math.max(max,testPath.getTotalLength());
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this function to calculate the distance between 2 points:

```js
function dist(x1,y1, x2,y2) {
  let dx = x2 - x1;
  let dy = y2 - y1;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

In your case the last line begins at `x1=0; y1=20` and ends at `x2=150; y2=20`

Of course you may also need a way to split the `d` attribute and extract the values for x1,y1,x2,y2.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, seems like you missunderstood my question... I obviously know how to measure the distance between points and write a simple function using `a²+b²=c²`... My example was only meant to show the problem with complicated paths. In reality I'm dealing with paths like the following, including beziers and arcs: `d="M23.64 4.05a10.53 [...]-.37zM6.76 8.45a6.74 6.74 0 0 1-3.06 2.68 6.74 6.74 0 0 1 1.86 3.6 6.74 6.74 0 0 1 3.06-2.66 6.74 6.74 0 0 1-1.86-3.61zm2.92 10.29c-.3.49-.67.93-1.07 1.32l1.53.2c-.2-.48-.36-1-.46-1.52zm-1.43 5.35c.1.3.17.6.23.92.17-.26.35-.51.55-.75-.26-.07-.52-.12-.78-.17z"`